# How to set mouse wheel scroll to page length per click

Tags: xfce, mouse, scrolling

My Logitech Optical Generic 3-button Mouse scrolls only few lines at a time. I used desktop Xfce on several distros, including Manjaro, CentOS and MX Linux (though I didn't try Xubuntu yet).

I know I can increase scroll sensitivity in Firefox (about:config, set **mousewheel.default.delta_multiplier_y** to 1000 instead of 100), but I definitely need to scroll in other programs too. Editor **FeatherPad** allows to scroll a page, but only when the mouse is hovering scrollbar (which is very thin, as usual in Linux). I am new to Linux desktop environments but I'm trying to learn.

I found some advice about hacking configs of **libinput** (like set larger MOUSE WHEEL ANGLE), but they don't seem to work in my case, and don't seem to be very consistent with recent libinput docs.

I thought "**gpointing-device-settings**" could be useful, but its page on GitHub is missing, and anyway I see no .deb package in my installer.

I found some tool called "**imwheel**", which should emulate some additional events, but its installation and usage seem to require much technical knowledge and it might be days of research for me, with uncertain result.

How do I make my simple mouse, which scrolls pages on Windows easily, on my usual 8-years old computer, with recent MX Linux (Xfce), scroll a page at a time?

Comment: Take a look at the end of the page here : https://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-settings/mouse

Comment: @ctac_ , I tried `xinput list-props "Logitech USB Optical Mouse"` but it does not have any properties related to scroll distance or wheel angle. So there seems to be no solution.